Existence of a foliation never tangent to a vector field?
Given a never vanishing vector field $X$ on a manifold $\mathcal M$, is there always a foliation of co-dimension 1 that is never tangent to $X$ ?
In other words, can we find a never vanishing 1-form $\tau$ such that $\tau\wedge\mathrm d \tau=0$ and $\tau_\mu X^\mu \not=0$ everywhere on $\mathcal M$?
If the answer is YES, then can we choose this foliation, and the 1-form $\tau$, such that $\mathrm d \tau = 0$ (or even $\tau = \mathrm d t$) and $\tau_\mu X^\mu = 1$ everywhere on $\mathcal M$?
The motivation for that question is the study of Carrollian structures in Physics. In this context, I have two additional hypothesis which can be considered in the questions above if the answer is NO in general:
(1) $\mathcal M = \mathbb R\times\Sigma$, with $\Sigma$ a closed 3-manifold;
(2) $X$ is a complete vector field.
Ideally, I would like the leafs of the foliation (if it exists) to be $\Sigma$.

If you ask for an exact $1$-form $\tau = du$ with $\tau(X)=Xu \ge c >0$ (with $c$ being a constant), you constrain the dynamics: if $\gamma\colon [0,\infty)\to \mathcal M$ is an orbit, then $v(t) = u(\gamma(t))$ satisfies $\dot v \ge c$ and hence $v$ is unbounded, which means that $\gamma$ eventually has to exit every compact set (in this sense the flow is non-trapping).
